# How do I get the Win 10 taskbar to hide again if I trigger it to popup then click outside the taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I've seen a question on here about fixing the taskbar but I'm not sure if this is expected behavior or not. I want it to behave like the OSX taskbar: shows when I am in that activation zone, hides if I click something or move the mouse outside the activation zone.

I play games in windowed mode and the taskbar is a constant source of annoyance. I move the mouse into that area and it pops up and stays popped up even if I move it back out.

I've restarted the Explorer process, that didn't work.

[image: Settings].

Comment: That does not appear to be normal behavior -- if one does *not* click on the Taskbar, it disappears when the cursor moves outside it. However, I do find the Taskbar pops up too quickly if I accidentally mouse to the edge, so use Taskbar Activate, to delay its popup.

Comment: What is Taskbar Activate ? A tool?

Comment: Yeah it seems like a bug, I just don't see any way to fix it.

Comment: Taskbar Activate is a third-party tool used to control the Windows Taskbar, such as delaying popup during accidental mouse-over. It was last changed in 1999 (!), v.2.4, and *still* seems to work well. It's available from http://pmdevigne.free.fr/TaskbarActivate.html and https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Taskbar-Activate.shtml . Before installing *any* software, check it at VirusTotal!